# How to repair this metal corner siding?

Tags: repair, exterior, siding, metal

My dog run attaches to the back side of my house, and every time my dog sees or hears something in the front lawn worth chasing after, she goes tearing after it around the side of the house. When she does this her lead crashes against the side of the house and his been wearing away at the siding.

This has been happening for almost a year now, and as you can see, the area where the dog lead smacks against the house has rubbed the metal corner pieces loose, and in some cases, completely off the corner of the house.

[image]

[image]

As the photos show there are several areas where felt paper and even plywood are visible. This *has* to be fixed immediately. What are these metal pieces called? Are they universal or do I need to find the exact model made by the manufacturer? How do I install them, and for the ones that are just loose (but still connected), how do I fasten and seal them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Siding Corner Caps"
Or often just tin caps. They should be available. Or you could have some fabricated, or perhaps adapt some intended for other siding materials.

Install by running a thin bead of caulk along the end of each clapboard, slide the top under the upper course and press into the caulk. Nail underneath at each corner with a small corrosion resistant ring shank nail.

Alternately, for a different look, take them all off, trim the clapboards back a bit and install a vertical wooden lapped corner.

Comment: Thanks @bcworkz (+1) - a few followup questions: (1) What kind of caulk should I use, general exterior? Or is there something specialized for tin-wood adhesions? (2) Can you explain what you mean by the words "*top*" and "*upper course*" when you say: *...slide the **top** under the **upper course** and press into the caulk.*? Thanks again!

Comment: he means slide the top edge of each cap under the lip of the row of siding/cap above it.  This way each cap will overlap the one below it, the same way each row of siding does.

Comment: I would use siliconized latex caulk. It's pretty durable, and you can paint over any that spills out and does not get removed. Thanks Jason for jumping in in my absence.

Answer (score 2):

The pieces you need are called Hardieplank corner pieces. With a little research I found Simplicity tool.com. They come in a variety of sizes based on exposure and thickness. Long term you need to address the dog run. If you can get it close maybe a sixfoot fence post right at the corner would protect the siding.

Comment: I had the same idea - A galvanized fence post at the corner would be most durable in that situation. But that was 10 years ago and the dog is probably pretty slow now.